# Regular Expression to find 3 spaces at the start of a new line followed by any char

Tags: regex

I have to edit a rst file with hundreds of lines and replace 3 spaces with 4 spaces at the start of a line. The problem is that there are some lines with more than 3 spaces which have to stay as they are. Also, I must not recive 3 spaces in the middle of the line.

I am looking for a regular expression that gives me 3 spaces followed by any character at the start of a line.

I really apprecite the help. Maybe someone is fluent in regex ;)

Comment: Regexpressions are used in a white range of programming languages. Each language uses a dialect of it. Please add a tag of programming language which you want to use. You can doing it by click on the link "edit" underneath your post.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "3 spaces followed by any non whitespace/newline character at the start of a line"

If you want to capture only the three spaces:

`^\s{3}(?=\S)`

If you want to capture the spaces as well as the character:

`^\s{3}\S`

Explanation:
`^` start of line
`\s` whitespace
`{3}` exactly 3
`(?=\S)` lookahead for any non whitespace

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `^\W{3}\w`

Check it out: https://regex101.com/r/NYJIRr/1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You need this one `(?m)^\s{3}(?=\S)`